# SpriteKit not showing node count

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

In Xcode with SpriteKit, in every project I have showsNodeCount set to true but I see only the fps. This is so odd. I can't figure out what is causing the problem.

```
if let scene = GameScene(fileNamed:"GameScene") {
        // Configure the view.
        let skView = self.view as! SKView
        skView.showsFPS = true
        skView.showsNodeCount = true

        /* Sprite Kit applies additional optimizations to improve rendering performance */
        skView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true

        /* Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window */
        scene.size = skView.bounds.size
        skView.presentScene(scene)
    }
```

Maybe because I'm using Xcode 7 beta 3? (even with the old betas same problem).

Comment: Still in beta. Node count, draw count etc don't show up. Even some instrument debugging tools related to drawing are not working. I'm guessing this might have something to do with Sprite Kit working with both OpenGL and Metal? Apple is definitely aware of this, should be fixed soon.

Comment: @EpicByte Oh thanks for the reply. I was going crazy about that haha :)

Answer (score 1):

As you have probably already discovered, this was a beta issue and has been fixed. It works in Xcode 7 beta 5. The draw and quad count have also returned! :)

[image: Screenshot from simulator iPad 2, iOS 9 beta 5]